# How does "background:cover" CSS property works?

Tags: css, background

I'm currently "fighting" with an issue with parts of a website that I need to be fully covered by a picture. Thus, I tried the background:cover CSS property.
Well, to be complete, I didn't actually chose : I'm working with a Wordpress theme but I largely customize it. Options included in the theme allows to chose between "standard" background for headers or a "cover" one.

But it doesn't work as I imagined.
Here's how I assumed it works : given a resolution of 1920px wide, and, on the website, a header vertical space of 500px. If I make a 1920x500px background and place it as a Background with the Cover property, isn't it supposed to not be enlarged and displayed on it's original size, since the resolution allows it ?

If I make a background wider and higher than the "container", again with the Cover property, isn't it supposed to shrink ?

Doesn't Cover property supposed to resize itself until it matches either the width nor the height of the container ?

Currently, it seems that every background I made, with several sizes, are enlarged, not giving the expected result. Yet, I give it a height equal to the height of the container, and and width way superior of the width of the container. I don't understand why it's enlarged.

Can you tell me if I correctly understand the way the CSS background:cover property works or if it may be an issue in the code ?

What do you say ? PEBKAC nor not PEBKAC ? :D

I hope I made my asking understandable.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Nex4, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: For more in depth questions regarding coding, I would advise you to post questions to http://stackoverflow.com/. You will need to post code when creating your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the container. If the container is the window/body then the image will be greater than the smallest length.

From [MDN - background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

**Cover**

> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to
>   be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater
>   than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background
>   positioning area.

For testing purposes check out this codepen to see how the different background properties effect the background image: http://codepen.io/obojdi/pen/lHgbF/

Here is another in-depth tutorial going over all of the CSS3 background size properties

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/